# ArrayList class add method

Tags: java, arraylist

We're writing an add method that adds an entry in a specified position. It's supposed to add it wherever the position asked. If the position is between 1 and the size of the array then it does the function. In our book, linkedlists start at 1 instead of 0. No idea why but please note. What is my problem? I'm having trouble with the for loop. I know my issue is somewhere within it but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It won't add anything whatsoever and none of my tests work. Ensure capacity makes the array larger accordingly (if it gets full)

```
public ArrayList()
{
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
} // end default constructor

public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
{
    mySize = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")       
    T[] tempArray = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
    myArray = tempArray;
} // end constructor
private void ensureCapacity()
{
    if (mySize == myArray.length)
        myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, 2 * myArray.length);
}


public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry)
{
    if (newPosition >= 1 && (newPosition <= mySize || newPosition <= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)) {
        ensureCapacity();
        int index = newPosition-1;
        for (int i = mySize; i > 0; i--) {
            myArray[i] = myArray[i-1];
            if (i == index)
            myArray[index] = newEntry;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end add
```

Here's the test code:

```
System.out.println("Testing clear() ");
    myList.clear();

    System.out.println("List should be empty: ");
    System.out.println("Is list empty? " + myList.isEmpty());

    System.out.println("-------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("Create a new list of max size 8.\n");
    myList = new ArrayList<String>(8);  // 8 is max size

    System.out.println("Testing add at position ");
    System.out.println("Add 15 at position 1: returns " + myList.add(1, "15"));
    System.out.println("Add 25 at position 2: returns " + myList.add(2, "25"));
    System.out.println("Add 35 at position 3: returns " + myList.add(3, "35"));
    System.out.println("Add 99 at position 0: returns " + myList.add(0, "99"));
    System.out.println("Add 99 at position 9: returns " + myList.add(9, "99"));

    System.out.println("\n\nList should contain\n15 25 35 ");
    displayList(myList);

    System.out.println("Is List empty? " + myList.isEmpty());

    System.out.println("Add 19 at position 1: returns " + myList.add(1, "19"));
    System.out.println("Add 39 at position 3: returns " + myList.add(3, "39"));
    System.out.println("Add 29 at position 2: returns " + myList.add(2, "29"));
    System.out.println("Add 55 at position 7: returns " + myList.add(myList.getLength()+1, "55"));
    System.out.println("Add 65 at position 8: returns " + myList.add(8, "65"));

    System.out.println("\n\nList should contain\n19 29 15 39 25 35 55 65");
    displayList(myList);

    System.out.println("Is List empty? " + myList.isEmpty());
```

Comment: I think it is a logic thing. maby you should start at the index where you want to insert it at and then move up. Instead of moving down your array. Also a bit more code would be good like what does ensure capacity do?

Comment: where do you set mySize ?

Comment: Added the methods where that happens. If someone makes a new arraylist and doesn't set a size, it goes to default size.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you increase mySize after adding an element.

Also, at the beginning, mySize is 0, so your for-loop is never entered.

Answer (score 1):

If i had to implement a add at position without using the System.arraycopy native method i would implement it like this:
You can also check the source code out of arraylist(package java.util);

You will want to limit the length instead of going through to the end of your array you can make it stop at the current size of your array. But i dont see you currently storing a size anywhere.

```
  public static boolean add(int newPosition, String newEntry)
  {
    if (newPosition >= 1 && newPosition <= mySize) {
//      ensureCapacity(newPosition);//should you not pass in the index so that the function knows how big the array should be
      int startIndex = newPosition-1;
      mySize++;
      while (startIndex <= mySize)
      {
        String tempEntry = myArray[startIndex];
        myArray[startIndex] = newEntry;
        startIndex++;
        newEntry = tempEntry;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing braces around the if statement in your for loop, which is causing it to break out after the first time through the loop:

```
public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry)
    {
        if (newPosition >= 1 && (newPosition <= mySize || newPosition <= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)) {
        ensureCapacity();
        int index = newPosition-1;
        for (int i = mySize; i > 0; i--) {
            myArray[i] = myArray[i-1];

            // The break here needs to be associated with the if
            if (i == index) {
                myArray[index] = newEntry;
                // As Ridcully mentioned, you should increment your size here.
                mySize++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end add
```